# Do sections defined in different patches give the same element in an associated bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

We can read here in p. 10 (penultimate equation) that the sections on associated bundles (not necessarly vector bundle) are defined by functions $f:P\longrightarrow F$ that must satisfy the equivariance condition:
$$R^{\star}_{g}f=\rho({g^{-1}})\circ f$$
where $\rho$ is the representation of $G$ on $F$ that defines the associated bundle $P\times_{\rho}F$. In turn, we define a section on $P\times_{\rho}F$ by:
$$\tilde{s_{\alpha}}(m)=[(s_{\alpha}(m),(f\circ s_{\alpha})(m))]$$
where $s_{\alpha}:U_{\alpha}\longrightarrow U_{\alpha}\times G$ is a section in $P$, and $[...]$ denotes the class of equivalent elements defining the associated bundle.

I remark that:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\tilde{s}_{\beta}(m) & = & \left[\left(s_{\beta}(m),(f\circ s_{\beta})(m)\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m)g_{\alpha\beta}(m),(f\circ s_{\beta})(m)\right)\right]\;\text{(}g_{\alpha\beta}\text{are the transition functions of }P\text{)}\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),(\rho(g_{\alpha\beta}(m))\circ f\circ s_{\beta})(m)\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),(R_{g_{\beta\alpha}(m)}^{\star}f\circ s_{\beta})(m)\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),(f\circ R_{g_{\beta\alpha}(m)}\circ s_{\beta})(m)\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),f\left[s_{\beta}(m)g_{\beta\alpha}(m)\right]\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),f\left[s_{\alpha}(m)\right]\right)\right]\\
 & = & \left[\left(s_{\alpha}(m),(f\circ s_{\alpha})(m)\right)\right]\\
 & = & \tilde{s}_{\alpha}(m)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In the title: does an associated bundle have a global section as my calculation suggest?

Comment: Your computation requires that $s_\alpha$ and $s_\beta$ are restrictions of the same section to different trivial neighborhoods in which case yes, of course they take the same value at a given point upon pulling back.

Comment: Of course - I wanted an answer to this question and it has already been answered on stack exchange by ubungu. Though your calculation seems a bit confusing. I think I have managed to shorten it:

https://www.overleaf.com/2518847vdrtvp#/6592772/